# $wpdb insert is not work

Tags: wp-query, query

I try different way for insert data in custom table but is not work and there are not errors.

Sometimes is save, but most of the time is not.

I check around the web, but no solution is working for me.

my last method is:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO `$table_name` 
(`name`, `email`, `phone`, `address`, `message`, `rq`, `url`) 
values 
(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %d, %s)",
$name, $email, $phone, $address, $msg, 1, $url);

$wpdb->query($sql);
```

I print $sql and paste on phpmyadmin SQL and save it, so the query doesn't have any problem, but still not save.

Why this happen?

I already try with array and $wpdb->insert(), same problem.

**EDIT:**
**it is solved. it was an integer passed like string, thanks to everybody**

Comment: Where and how are you running this code? Where are your variables defined? Particularly `$table_name`. What is the structure of your table? What is the primary key?

Comment: everything is defined and if I print $sql, copy and paste in phpmyadmin, the query is work.

Comment: And I am running this code by my own plugin with ajax. It wired that, same inputs sometimes is saving sometimes is not

Comment: Please add to your question that you're running this after a call to `admin-ajax.php`. This is an important detail.

Answer (score 3):

First insert the global.

```
global $wpdb;
```

Then You have to check your quotes properly.

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO `$table_name`      
       (`name`,`email`,`phone`,`message`,`rq`,`url`) 
 values ($name, $email, $phone, $address, $msg, 1, $url)");
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

OR

```
$wpdb->insert('$table_name', array(
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email,
    'phone' => $phone, // ... and so on
));
```